# .Net 2.0 to .Net 4.5 Upgrade Tool?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2012, migration, upgrade, code-analysis

Is it there any tool which will upgrade/convert/migrate my .net 2.0 framework code to .net 4.5 framework?

By default visual studio does this ,but i am looking for the tool which will analyse my code and migrate to 4.5 with analysis report.

for e.g if i migrate a form written at 2.0 framework to 4.5 framework,it should recommend me with the alternative keyword for migration to 4.5 framework.
Did anyone came across such a tool?any addin/extension for visual studio ?or any separate third party tools available for it?

EDIT : is it there any tool which suggest me to use a alternative to this ,  this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh419162%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) provides alternative for all specific keywords/commands is it there any tool which suggest me while migrating

for e.g have a look at the below screenshot :

[image]

Here vs auto suggests an alternative obsolete type,i would like to get pre analyse reports of obsolete types before migration

Comment: .NET 2.0 code is perfectly valid .NET 4.0, as the 4.0 is backwards compatible. In fact most of the types that are the same in 2.0 and 4.0 are being referenced from the 2.0 libraries by the framework. The only thing you __may__ need to convert is the `.csproj` and `.sln` files, which VS does by default

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no tool because you do not need such a tool. Just open the project in Visual Studio 2013 or 2012. That's it. You're done.

Comment: is it there any tool which suggest me to use a alternative to this ,for e.g http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh419162(v=vs.110).aspx this link provides alternative for all specific keywords/commands is it there any tool which suggest me while migrating

Comment: You do not need any alternatives. Why do you think you need alternatives? Please give an example.

Comment: When you talk about alternatives, you are apparently talking about alternatives to obsolete types. Have you tried just opening the code in VS2013 and building it? The error messages tell you alternatives.

Comment: is it there any way to preanalyze before opening in vs 2013?

Comment: What are you talking about? Just build the project, and Visual Studio will make suggestions about how to get rid of the "Obsolete Member" compiler warnings. What are you afraid of?

Comment: Microsoft provides the obsolete member list which we can check, but also we need the recommendations like instead of collections use generic collection (arraylist to list<type>) which can change the code to .net 4.5 standards and increase performance

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50778/discussion-between-blueberry-vignesh4303-and-john-saunders)

Comment: Let's not. It's a waste of time talking to someone who has gone off on the wrong track and insists there is no other track.

Comment: Can we know what options are needed to increase performance during migration. Eg: use dictionary for keyvaluepair, hashtable to increase performance

Comment: Why do you assume that the options you mention would improve performance? The only sensible way to do performance tuning is 1. Measure the current performance using a profiler tool, noting where most time is being spent, then 2. Change that code to improve the performance, then 3. Goto 1.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio already having inbuilt tool to migrate old project to new one. But, it will not upgrade your code. just updating your project file and solution file that can be loaded in current version. check this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms185327%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).